# Generate SQL migration script with EF 6 without connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way to generate a SQL migration script using the *udpate-database* command without specifying a connection string?

I'd like to generate a SQL script for my database during the automated build process to deploy the new version of the database on different environments, different databases. But when the continuous integration server is compiling the solution it do not known the connection string of the target database(s).

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: You could look at running migrate.exe externally on your build server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

Comment: Could you run the migration against a temporary database, like LocalDB or an .mdf file?  Are all the databases you're targeting at the same version?

Comment: Hello @Jerome Thievent, what was your solution to the question?